# Instance member 'readLineSync' can't be accessed using static

Tags: dart

I'm trying to make a BMI calculator as a beginner project, as I am learning Dart. However, when I'm trying to take input, it outputs an error

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

  print('What is your weight in kgs?');
  var weight = Stdin.readLineSync();

  print("Your weight is $weight");


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to call `readLineSync` on the class, not on an instance. Since `readLineSync` isn't `static`, you'll need to call this on an instance of `Stdin`.

There's a global instance of `Stdin` named [stdin](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/stdin.html) exposed through `dart:io` that you can use for this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new and didn't understand that entirely, could you please show an example?

Comment: Just change `Stdin` to `stdin` and your code will work as-is. If you're new to Dart, I highly recommend looking through the [language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) in its entirety.